# Why I can't get body form Angular

Tags: angular, api, go, http-post

I use angular to get information register html and I post to path api it work but print word "work" and I cant not get value In body and I test path post use
postman it show firstname.......................................................................................................................................

server.go

```html
package main

import (
 "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
 "github.com/gorilla/mux"
 "net/http"
)

func main() {

 router := mux.NewRouter()
 router.HandleFunc("/register", Createuser).Methods("POST")
 headers := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
 methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"})
 origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
 http.ListenAndServe(":12345", handlers.CORS(headers, methods, origins)(router))

}


func Createuser(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
 request.ParseForm()
    print(request.FormValue("firstName"))
 print("work")
}
```

register.component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AlertService, UserService } from '../_services';

@Component({templateUrl: 'register.component.html'})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    registerForm: FormGroup;
    loading = false;
    submitted = false;

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            firstName: ['', Validators.required],
            lastName: ['', Validators.required],
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
        });
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;

        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value)
 
    }
}
```

user.service.ts

```html
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {User} from '../_models';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  register(user: User) {
     return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/register`, {
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName : user.lastName,
      username : user.username,
      password : user.password
    })
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: are you facing any error?

Comment: not have error. @PardeepJain

Comment: Did you try setting the Content-Type headers explicitly? What _do_ you get in that print statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it could be that your go server is expecting a `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm

But angular is submitting the form as a json object.

To debug what is happening check the outgoing response from chrome to your backend
Do this by enabling "Log XmlHttpRequest from the settings menu in chrome devtools.

You should then be able to se that the body is JSON.

Try using this to parse the body instead

```
func test(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    var t test_struct
    err := decoder.Decode(&t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(t.Test)
}
```